# Automatically resize an image to fit in a container

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How do I automatically resize an image to fit it into a container? I would like to have a blank background for the container. Currently it is like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="row">
                    <img src ="haha.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have a container where I could fit the image inside, automatically resizing the image.

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: try `img {
    width: 100%;
}`

Comment: Sorry where do i place it?

Comment: Actually it is the image that should get re-sized to fit the container. There's a helper class called `.img-responsive` for images that holds a `max-width: 100%` and a `height: auto` declaration to make sure the image would fit the containing block while keeping its aspect ratio.

Comment: in css tag place it @aceminer

Comment: @HashemQolami .img-responsive has max-width

Comment: @debin So..? The OP wouldn't want to enlarge the image, would s/he?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add class "img-responsive" to your image tag.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src ="haha.png" alt = "Alternative Text" />
```

> Images in Bootstrap 3 can be made responsive-friendly via the addition
>   of the .img-responsive class. This applies max-width: 100%;, height:
>   auto; and display: block; to the image so that it scales nicely to the
>   parent element.

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images

Answer (score 1):

You should write that code in your style sheet.

```
<style>
  .row{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
   }
</style>
```